# DateAdd (y, -1, getdate()) Not working

Tags: sql-server, dateadd

I'm trying to find all records that took place in the last year (to the day/date, not worried about time).

My SQL is:

```
dm.fromdatetime >= dateadd(y,-1,getdate())
and dm.fromdatetime <= getdate()
```

Not sure what is missing here, it seems like this should work.  Suggestions?

Comment: what is the data type of fromdatetime?

Comment: Looking for data for the last 365 days from today (or whenever this script happens to be run). And this is in MS SQL 2008.

Comment: FromDateTime is a "datetime" data type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use "yy", not "y":

```
dm.fromdatetime >= dateadd(yy,-1,getdate())
and dm.fromdatetime <= getdate()
```

As per [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819.aspx), "y" is "dayofyear", and not year.

Comment: Or even better, use `YEAR` instead of any shortcuts

Comment: Assuming last 365 days up through "now", how would you use "YEAR"?

Comment: `DATEADD(YEAR,-1,GETDATE())`

Comment: True. Or, YYYY. Key thing is, don't use Y.

Comment: Thanks, I think I should go with dateadd(day,-365,getdate()) to make sure it goes back 1 year. Feels like if I use dateadd(year,-1,getdate()) it will pull of 2013 instead of Dec. 10, 2013 and forward.

Comment: @MISNole That's the wrong way, use 1 year instead. What happens when you have a leap year?